# How would this be better written For adding php external data to a jquery select

Tags: php, ajax, cordova, jquery-mobile

I want to submit an app using phonegap, My app uses a lot of php which i know apple do not like so much and just decline the app and say its best to have a web app. I have an example index.html here

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
        <title>
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/logout-button.min.css" />
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.cookies.2.2.0.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
var uid = $.cookies.get( 'uid' );
 if(uid == null)
                 {
                window.location ='account-login.html'; }
                 else
                 { }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="index4">

           <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <a data-role="button" data-direction="reverse" data-rel="back" data-transition="slide"
         data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left" class="ui-btn-left">
            Back
        </a>
        <h3>
           Event Details
        </h3>
    </div>

         <div data-role="content">
             <form id="eventForm" name="eventForm">
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                            <label for="event">
                                Event
                            </label>
                            <input name="eventname" id="eventname" placeholder="eventname" value="" type="text" />
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                            <label for="about">
                                About
                            </label>
                            <textarea name="about" id="about" placeholder="about" value=""></textarea>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="dates">
                                Choose Dates
                            </label>
                            <div id="with-altField"></div>
                            <input type="hidden" id="altField" name="dates">
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                            <label for="enddate">
                                End Date
                            </label>
                            <div id="with-altfield1"></div>
                            <input type="hidden" id="altField1" name="enddate">
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <script>
                            $.get('event-details.php', function(data){
                            $('#yourdiv').html(data);
                            });
                        </script>   
                        <div id="yourdiv"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="manual">Add Emails</label>
                        <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="emails" id="emails"></textarea>
                    </div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitEventButton">
                </form>
        </div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

I call event-details.php here

```
<?
require_once("../backend/functions.php");
dbconn();
                            $id = $CURUSER["id"];
                            $res = "SELECT username,email,status FROM users left join cal_contacts on cal_contacts.contactid = users.id WHERE cal_contacts.userid = $id";
                            $res1 = mysql_query($res);
                        ?>
                        <label for="select-choice-1" class="select">
                                Choose Contacts:
                            </label>
                            <select name="contacts[]" id="contacts" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
                        <?
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res1))
                            { 
                            print "<option value=$row[email]>$row[email] ($row[status])</option>";
                            }
                        ?>
                        </select>
                        <?
```

I have the select-menu created through php. I was wondering if there was another way to do this so the complete select html doesn't have to be on the php script. This would mean that it would be harder for me to change my app once submitted and i'm sure apple would accept it alot easier.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is just to remove the PHP processing on that HTML, you could just move it somewhere else as a web service then get it via ajax request. Then you can just use json, etc. to fetch the data and populate your select menu.

here is a [doc on jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)! regarding how to make ajax requests.

i found a tutorial here which seem similar on what you want to achieve.

[How To Write A Simple PHP/MySQL Web Service for an iOS App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app)!